# How to save variables to be later accessed?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a text based game in which you have different levels of different aspects of life and other variables. I'm trying to save them to some sort of file so I can get them back later.

So far, this is what I have with the variables:

```
public class baseLevels {
    public boolean gameOver = false;

    //100 is a normal level
    public int happyLevel = 100;
    public int sleepLevel = 100;
    public int angerLevel = 100;
    public int healthLevel = 100;
    public int popularityLevel = 100;
    public int smartLevel = 100;
    public int weight = 100;

    //0 = Single 1 = Not very close, but dating 2 = close and dating 3 = engaged 4 = married
    public int relationshipStatus = 0; 
    public boolean children = false;
    public int numberOfChildren = 0;

    //Tests if the player is injured, 1-5 on severeness
    public boolean injured = false;
    public int severity = 1;
    public boolean healthCare = false;

    //Money status: 1 is poor, 5 is rich
    public int money = 5000;
    public int wealthStatus = 1;  

    //Family is alive or dead
    public boolean momDead = false;
    public boolean dadDead = false;
    public boolean sisterDead = false;
    public boolean brotherDead = false;
    public boolean grandmaDead = false;
    public boolean grandpaDead = false;

    //Misc. variables
    public boolean car = false;
    public boolean house = false;
    public boolean dead = false;
    public boolean likeMusic = false;


}
```

After looking at the property method someone posted, I like it, but I need a way to set a property value as a number. When I try this, I get an error saying I can't have a string and an integer.

Comment: ok, so you have the variables and the code needs to be written?

Comment: @devnull yes that is correct

Answer (score 4):

[java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) is probably the best class for something simple like this. It has built-in methods for loading from a file and saving to a file.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream("data.props"));
String someProp = props.getProperty("myName");
props.setProperty("myName", "John Smith");
props.store(new PrintWriter("data.props"));
```

Comment: Might be worth closing those streams - the OP will just copy paste this code and that will cause issues.

Comment: Is there any way the first arg in `props.setProperty`the `myName`could be a string but the second `John Smith` could be set to a number? So a string and then an integer?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use object serialization.

To use serialization your class must implement the Serializable interface.

Suppose you have an instance of your class baseLevels that you want to write to a file, "save.dat":

```
baseLevels obj = new baseLevels();
```

Using object serialization you would first create an object output stream to your save file: "save.dat".

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream( new FileOutputStream( "save.dat" ) );
```

To write your baseLevels instance, obj, to the file you would invoke writeObject( obj ):

```
out.writeObject( obj );
```

Always remember to close the stream:

```
out.close();
```

To restore the object to the state it was in when you wrote it to the save file, you would use an object input stream:

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream( new FileInputStream( "save.dat" ) );
```

And invoke method readObject() which reads the next object from the input stream. The return type of readObject() is Object so we need to cast it to the appropriate type; in this example we have only written one object and we know that it is of type baseLevels thus we can safely cast the returned object to baseLevels:

```
baseLevels obj = (baseLevels)in.readObject().
```

close the stream:

```
in.close();
```

Complete example(Assumes that baseLevels implements Serializable):

```
// Initialize
String      fileName    = "save.dat";
baseLevels  lvl1        = new baseLevels();

// Set level attributes
lvl1.angerLevel = 0;
lvl1.happyLevel = 200;

// Write level
try( ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream( new FileOutputStream( fileName ) ) ) {
    out.writeObject( lvl1 );
}
catch( IOException e ) {
    System.err.println( e.getMessage() );           
}

// Read level
baseLevels lvl2;

try( ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream( new FileInputStream( fileName ) ) ) {
    lvl2 = (baseLevels)in.readObject();     
}
catch( IOException e ) {
    System.err.println( e.getMessage() );           
} 
catch( ClassNotFoundException e )  {
    System.err.println( "Class definition could not be found" );
    System.err.println( e.getMessage() );
}
```

For more information on serialization you should look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html.

The example linked to from the above site - because it is easy to miss if you only skim the site: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/ObjectStreams.java )

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. When providing an answer, please post the relevant content to answer the question in your post and use links to refer to more info for research. Your answer **must not be** the content in the links. Also, when providing code examples, they should be complete or understandable from the context of the question, for example what's `out` and what's `in` (for experienced programmers we may know these are `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`, but it's not for all readers).

Comment: Thank you for your constructive feedback. I have edited my answer accordingly. Any further suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As far as a `Game Development`  concerned in java its best approach to user `MVC`
 also you might be using all of the classes and variables differently like you mentioned

```
100 is a normal level 
0 = Single 1 = Not very close, but dating 2 = close and dating 3 = engaged 4 = married
Tests if the player is injured, 1-5 on severeness
Money status: 1 is poor, 5 is rich
```

and to use them you will need some getters and setters in your classes so its better approach if you use `Beans` and a separate package for all of the beans with different `Bean` classes.
[javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) and 
[Collections](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_collections.htm)  inorder to use and map you data with objects

[Saving Variables in game](http://www.wowwiki.com/Saving_variables_between_game_sessions)